# Remove background colour in ggpairs from GGally

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I'm plotting all my graphs with theme_bw() in ggplot2, and now i'd like to apply the same (or similar) theme to a ggpairs plot of GGally. I tried it this way, but this seems to have no effect:

```
p <- ggpairs(vars, columns=1:ncol(vars), lower=list(params=c(alpha = 0.5, theme(panel.background = element_blank()))))
```

Is there a way to apply a ggplot2-theme to a ggpairs plot ?

Comment: Precede your plot with `theme_set(theme_bw()) `

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood you problem very well. Have you already tried the following simple solution? I used the **iris** dataset for the example. This solution is applied only to non data elements (not applied to geoms).

```
      ggpairs(iris, mapping = aes(color = Species)) + 
      theme_bw()
```